# Error Invalid cast from 'Int32' to 'DateTime'

Tags: casting

In my database, i have table :

```
ID          int 
UserName    nvarchar(50)    
NoiDung         ntext   
Trangthai   nvarchar(50)    
GhiChu          ntext
NgayThucHien    datetime    
ThoiHan         datetime
```

And SQL procedure to Insert:

```
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_DBangKe]
@UserName nvarchar(50),
@NoiDung ntext,
@TrangThai nvarchar(50),
@GhiChu ntext,
@Ngay datetime,
@Han datetime
AS
    INSERT INTO DBangKe
    (
        UserName,
        NoiDung,
        TrangThai,
        GhiChu,
        NgayThucHien,
        ThoiHan
    )VALUES
    (
        @UserName,
        @NoiDung,
        @TrangThai,
        @GhiChu,
        @Ngay,
        @Han
    )
```

In my Project Web, i have APSxGridView to show and allow insert, delete, edit.

1. APSxGridView load with no rows
2. When i Click Insert, and type value, then select date from AspxDateedit. Click Update, its show error:
   Invalid cast from 'Int32' to 'DateTime'.
   How i can repair this?